# Assigning a component to Declaratives under @component throws compile error

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Not sure why a component is not assignable to declaratives property of @component. This statement (**directives: [ChildComponent]**) in parent throws compile error. My code purpose is to pass a data value from parent to child. I heard that with RC6 declaratives doesn't work, so I declared the child component in declarations of ngModule and the compile error was resolved but can't get the data in the child view.

```
Parent component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child-input.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>parent here!</h1>
  <child-component [child] = 'parent'></child-component>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  parent = 'parent to child';

}


child component:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<h1>{{child}}</h1>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() child : string;

}
```

Here are my CLI version details:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.8
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.8
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Thanks
Yesp

Answer (score 0):

*"I declared the child component in declarations of ngModule and the compile error was resolved but can't get the data in the child view"*

It's because if you want to pass a string to child component, you should pass it like `[child] = "'parent'"`, not just `'parent'`:

```
<child-component [child]="'parent'"></child-component>
```

Comment: Your code works if you want to pass a hard coded string,, but I think he is trying to pass the `parent` attribute to the child component and not just a string that says _parent_, therefore I think his code is correct at that point.

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt, yes, my example will pass the string `parent`, but we can pass whatever we want, in this case we don't need quotes inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to use a child *component* inside a parent *component*. This has nothing to do with *directives*, they serve a different purpose (either [attribute directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) or [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)). Unfortunately you're trying to declare it as such a directive in the **[directives]** attribute and the compiler does not like that. So just be clear, directives **!=** declarations. Here's the line that the compiler probably does not like:

```
directives: [ChildComponent]
```

The common way to use a *component* inside another *component* is by declaring it inside a *module*. If both components are in the same module (or folder, I'm not sure about that one) they both know about each other and can be used inside of each other, no need for declaration inside the components themselfs.

I'm currently not sure why your value is not correctly set in the child component, the code itself looks correct. What is it showing you in the browser? Is it showing a different text, is the child component and its content missing at all or is the **h1** tag just empty?